# Find column names in executed query sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table that stores SQL queries. I retrieve a query according to a condition and store it in a variable:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
ID       |  Query
---------------------------------------------------------
1        | 'Select Id,Name from Student'
2        | 'Select Id,Name,Father_Name from Student'
3        | 'Select Id,Name,Email from Student_Detail'

....
---------------------------------------------------------
```

For example, a variable `@sql` might have the first query from above:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @sql = 'Select Id,Name from Student'
```

I execute this query using:

```
Exec(@sql)
```

The problem is, how do I know which columns are used in that query? I'm trying to achieve something like what ColdFusion does with `query.ColumnList`, which returns the column list used in that query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(query,8,CHARINDEX('from',query)-9) AS ColumnList
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Table name is already there in the query, so i cant have table name when executing query

Comment: @WaqarAhmed. Each query use of one table or more.

Answer (score -1):

this is a variant of mehdi lotfi solution but is equally weak in the sense that only gives you whatever is in between the select and from statements so if you have aliases or calculations or 'case' statements it will not work properly; it does work if the column list is straight forward comma separated columns:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(@SQL,'Select ',''), CHARINDEX(' from',REPLACE(@SQL,'Select ',''))) AS ColumnList
```

Comment: @Waqar Ahmed - I edited now, it should work for any table but with the same caveats

Answer (score -1):

Finally i managed to solve at my own using this solution.

```
Declare @sql varchar(1000)
Declare @valueList nvarchar(500)
Declare @tbl Table(Name varchar(100))
Declare @selectPos Int
Declare @fromPos Int
Declare @len Int
Declare @pos Int
Declare @prevpos Int
Declare @Delimeter varchar(2)

set @sql = 'Select Id,Name,Father_Name from Student'
set @selectPos = CHARINDEX('Select ', @sql, 1)+7 
set @fromPos = CHARINDEX('From ', @sql, 1)
set @len = @fromPos - @selectPos

set @valueList = SUBSTRING(@sql, @selectPos, @len)

set @Delimeter = ', '
set @pos = 1
set @prevpos = 0

while @pos > 0
Begin
    set @pos = charIndex(@Delimeter, @valueList, @pos)
    If @pos = 0
    Begin
        Insert into @tbl
        Select SUBSTRING(@valueList,@prevPos + 1,LEN(@valueList) - @prevpos)
        Break;
    End
    Insert into @tbl
    Select SUBSTRING(@valueList,@prevPos + 1,@pos-@prevpos - 1)
    set @prevpos = @pos
    set @pos = @pos + 1
 End

 select * from @tbl
```